# InternetAddress allows square bracket in localpart - bug?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, special-characters

As far as my research went, the string `[docxa]l.hri@txwt.org` is **not a syntactically valid email-address**, as the square brackets are not in a quoted-string.

However, the class `javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress` accepts this address as a valid one, because it simply strips the `[docxa]` part from the address in its `.parse(..)` method, which is invoked by the constructor.

Code comment in `InternetAddress.parse(String, boolean, boolean)` indicates, the implementers weren't sure themselves:

```
    case '[':   // a domain-literal, probably
```

That's the test I created to verify the problem, it's failing:

```
@Test
public void givenUnquotedEmailAddressWithSquareBracketsInLocalPartThenValidationShouldFail() {
    try {
        new InternetAddress("[docxa]l.hri@txwt.org", true).validate();
        fail("address should be invalid");
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // expected
    }
}
```

So, is this a bug in `InternetAddress`, or is my research or my understanding of it incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug that InternetAddress strips off the leading "[docxa]".